# Access laptop as public server

Tags: networking

I'm planning to use my laptop as server for my mobile application. This is to test the app before it goes live. For that, I need a public IP that should hit my laptop services whatever it host and accessible from public internet.

So are there any tool which can serve my need or configuration steps.

By the way, Hathaway was my ISP.

I knew buying a static IP and dedicated server would cover my need but I'm looking for better cheapest option. Can someone advice please.

Edit:

Firstly, Static IP from hathway was free.
Yes, it is a router based to which fibre cable of ISP was connected and I connected my router to it for getting wifi(not sure what to call this, router or modem).

I'll host openfire server in my laptop and it runs on 9090 with XMPP protocol.

My need is I should access the openfire services in laptop from public internet. Eg: I should access it from public wifi zone.

I will take care of up time. Of course I'm looking to test my mobile app and so no of users to access would be in my radar.

Comment: Need more info before this question can be meaningfully answered including: 1.  Cost of static from Hathaway, 2.  Type of Internet connection you have and (and model of router).  3.  Please clarify what you mean by "whatever it host an accessible from public interent - do you mean that this application needs to be publicly reachable when your laptop is not at home ?   4.  What ports/protocols does the application use ?

Comment: If its a fairly lightweight app and you know what you're doing, you're *much* better off getting a Vps and hosting off that.

Comment: @Geek. Thanks for your reply. I don't want the services to be up all the time. So I believe getting a VPS and hosting there is an option unless I cannot make it as I asked.

Comment: Journeyman's answer is probably the way to go. As for the actual question, if you have a normal IP from your ISP (static or dynamic, but a regular normal IP and not a RFC1918 one) then you can reach that from the Internet. It probably just requires forwariding some ports if you use NAT. And if you have multiple IPs (the way the Internet was designed) then no magic at all is needed. Just leave your computer at home and open the right ports.

Comment: PS: You can shut down services in a VPS. If you wish even based on `cron` or `at`  Or just log into the VPS, enable it. Give a demo, then log back in to the VPS and shut the software down.